Limiting the file size of .qcow2 files
Qcow 2 files are an open source file format for virtual machines. In my opinion, unlike .vmdk files, they do not offer the option of specifying a maximum file size. This means that they can constantly grow in size for various reasons.
What ways are there to limit the growth of the file size of .qcow2 files when used under Debian 12 derivatives such as LMDE6 to a certain value or to be able to achieve a fixed file size?
Perhaps they are better ideas, than to use a own partition for every .qcow file. One alternate idea can be possible, to use a file system for storing the .qcow file, which offer to set a quota by folder or by file for the file system, which are used to store the .qcow files. But that's are only ideas on this moment.

seems to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1746602/when-using-virtualbox-with-qcow2-how-to-set-the-size-of-qcow2-to-a-fixed-size

@Marcus Müller, read the question an you will see, booth are related on different aspects.

vmdk behaves exactly the same as qcow2 in this aspect: it will grow to the set virtual disk size and no more, but if you do snapshots, it can grow indefinitely (up to additional full virtual disk size with each additional snapshot). There is no intrinsic possibility to limit this in qcow2 nor vmdk.
How you expect this to be implemented: let's say a system needs to write a block into qcow2 image and that requires extension of the file beyond limit; what to do? Return ENOSPC, EIO or whatever error code is appropriate? Then set the size limit on the file system hosting the file.
This is very dangerous. Such a hard error will eventually reach the process that wanted to write a block, whatever it was; if that was a file system driver (of the file system that resides within the qcow2 file), and it was going to write some important metadata block, that file system will become corrupted, and nobody knows how hard it would be to recover.
Much better and safer is to implement the monitoring and notifications about approaching and exceeding the decided "maximum allowed" size.
This is the typical "fear of the overprovisioned storage"; any storage that reports the larger free space than it is physically available has the same problem and, generally, it is expected to be solved the same way, with proper monitoring and timely extension.
Also notice that the "apparent" size of the qcow2 file is not the same thing as the space it occupies in the hosting file system. It can be sparse; one way to create a sparse qcow2 is to preallocate it but not write completely; other way is to release parts of it, for instance, enable discards in qemu process that is using the file and issue discard command (SCSI UNMAP, ATA TRIM, using fstrim, blkdiscard, etc.) in the VM; the file will release some space (and it will be seen as the increase of the free space in the hosting file system), but ls will probably show the same. To see the "real" on-disk usage, use ls -s; the number is disk usage in kibibytes.

The qcow2 disk image format, like other dynamically allocated image formats such as VDI (used by Virtualbox), does not grow indefinitely with use. When creating such a disk image, you must specify its maximum size.  The filesystem(s) within the image may grow to occupy that size.
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 test.qcow2
qemu-img: test.qcow2: Image creation needs a size parameter

$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 test.qcow2 50G
Formatting 'test.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 cluster_size=65536 extended_l2=off compression_type=zlib size=53687091200 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
$ ls -l test.qcow2
-rw-r--r-- 1 myself myself 197408 May  6 14:22 test.qcow2

To create a pre-allocated qcow2 image file, use the additional -o preallocation=full option with qemu-img create.

Note a qcow2 disk image can have snapshots (which is one of the benefits of using that format) and as a result, the disk usage of the qcow2 file can grow beyond that of the disk it is meant to emulate.
