Need to use .qcow2 VM file format but only have VirtualBox
I only have VirtualBox.
I have a .qcow2 image I need to use.
VirtualBox supports several file formats, but not .qcow2
What are my options?
I'd much prefer not have to change to a different hypervisor.

VirtualBox is not based on Qemu.

It also doesn't support .qcow, as far as I'm aware. So, I think your question might be based on multiple misconceptions.

@Marcus Müller, I removed the "is based on" parts.

Have you tried using qcow2 images in VirtualBox? IIRC it supports them, not perfectly but enough to cover at least some scenarios. The manual doesn’t mention them but there are multiple references to qcow2 in the changelog.

@StephenKitt I'd say that the definition of the word "supported" here is important.  The qcow2 format is not supported. Such images may possibly work with Virtualbox, but they (wisely) do not give you any promises about stability etc.

@Alfred.37 You seem to have investigated this before: https://superuser.com/questions/1746602/when-using-virtualbox-with-qcow2-how-to-set-the-size-of-qcow2-to-a-fixed-size

@Kusalananda good point, and Alfred.37 updated the question to allude to qcow2 “support” just before my comment (but I hadn’t seen that until now).

@Marcus Müller, I removed the ".qcow(1)" part from question.

@Kusalananda that question seems to more be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775926/limiting-the-file-size-of-qcow2-files to me

One way to use a qcow2 (or any other format) image in the VirtualBox without conversion is to connect it to the host block device and let VirtualBox use that device.
Load nbd module:
modprobe nbd

Use qemu-nbd to connect the file to the device:
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /path/to/file.qcow2

Create a "fake" VMDK image that refers to the NBD instead of storing the data:
VBoxManage createmedium disk --filename /path/to/file.vmdk --format=VMDK --variant RawDisk --property RawDrive=/dev/nbd0

Then, by using this new file, you are accessing the original qcow2 file. Don't forget to disconnect the NBD after you have finished by using qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0.
You might need to allow your user to access the NBD device (typically, add the user into the disk group or alter modes on the /dev/nbd0 device node).
This way, you can use any format that qemu-nbd understands.
Last, but not least. There are so many questions from you about qcow2 and VirtualBox. It's like to marry an eel and an eagle. If you want to use qcow2 this much, instead of trying to use it in VirtualBox, learn how to use qemu for which the format was designed. It will utilize it in the most efficient and complete way.

maybe I don't want to use qcow2, but it is the only VM image format provided by a project (such as Arch)

This is clearly different problem than "use qcow2 for virtualbox". Just convert them to your native format, as @Kusalananda suggested. For this other question case his answer would be better solution than that I suggested.

Virtualbox does not support the use of qcow2 disk image files.
The disk image file formats currently supported by Virtualbox are VDI, VMDK, VHD, and HDD (ref: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vdidetails).
To use a qcow2 image with Virtualbox, you should first convert it to e.g. VDI, Virtualbox's native disk image format.  This can be done with qemu-img:
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 image.qcow2 -O vdi image.vdi

